# Replace pointers with std::optional in a recursive data structure

Tags: c++, tree, recursive-datastructures

Is it possible to replace pointers with `std::optional` in a recursive data structure?

For example, how would I replace the following pointer based `Tree`

```cpp
template< typename T >
struct Tree {
    T data;
    Tree* left;
    Tree* right;
};
```

with a `Tree` that uses `std::optional` instead of pointers?

I have tried this:

```cpp
template< typename T >
struct Tree {
    T data;
    std::optional< Tree< T > > left;
    std::optional< Tree< T > > right;
};
```

but the compiler greeted me with several screens of error messages about incomplete type `Tree<int>` used in type trait expression.

Comment: What is the size of `std::optional`? It would have to be infinite, to potentially store any number of recursive `Tree` object.

Comment: An `std::optional`, when it contains a value, stores that value directly. An `std::optional<T>` takes at least as much space as an entire `T` object. That means that in your proposed design, a `Tree<T>` would require _at least_ as much storage as a `T` object and two `Tree<T>` objects.

Comment: Thanks - I get it - I thought it stored a pointer behind the scenes.

Comment: Nope. Using a pointer would incur extra Rule of Three complexity and runtime costs allocating the object and chasing the pointer.

Comment: I would recommend using `std::optional<std::unique_ptr<Tree<T>>>`. This is more modern than pointers, takes care of cleaning up things and ensures that you don't get cycles in your tree.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is allowed to be empty, point to `nullptr`, and that makes `std::optional` redundant. Use one or the other, not both. In this case that would be `unique_ptr` since the asker already knows `std::optional` alone cannot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work this way. The idea behind `std::optional<>` is that it already contains storage for `Tree<T>`. Your `Tree<T>` would be of infinite size this way.

Comment: You should rephrase this. `std::optional` does not allocate anything; memory is allocated on the stack, using operator `new` or similar, but this is not part of the functionality of `std::optional` itself: [*"If an `optional<T>` contains a value, the value is guaranteed to be allocated as part of the optional object footprint, i.e. **no dynamic memory allocation ever takes place.**"*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: @fabian rewritten.